# scanf_s reading characters what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c, windows

```
{

    printf("Please give a random positive number for X: \n");
    scanf_s("%i", &X);
    char ch = getchar();
    char Gender;
    if (isdigit)
    {
        printf("Hay um... sorry what my i call you?");
        scanf_s("%i", Gender);

        printf("%lf \n" Gender ", if you may, please reread what i said, i asked you to give me a RANDOM NUMBER. \ncan you please explain to me why you gave me out of 1 through infinite numbers, a random letter? \n \n ");
    };
```

my problem is with ["%lf \n" Gender] saying that its expecting a [ ) ] can someone please explain what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A few issues here:

1. `scanf_s` takes a pointer to where you want to store the read value, so it should be `scanf_s("%i", &Gender);`
2. In C, you can't just insert a `char` into a string. I'm not sure exactly what you want from this, since `%lf` is a really weird format for printing a `char`, but that's what I'm assuming you want. In that case, you would want to move `Gender` to the end: `printf("%lf \n...letter? \n \n", Gender);`. This will insert `Gender` in the position of `%lf`.

Comment: `%i` takes a pointer to an `int`, not a pointer to a `char`.  To read an integer into a char, use `%hhi`.  To read an actual character, use `%c`

Comment: Also, `scanf_s` requires an additional *length* argument for formats of type `%c` and `%s` and `%[]`.